# Stylesheet doesn't gets applied on website after bundle (MVC)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundle

The issue is CSS Does not effect on website after bundle although all of bundle process is fine

From the view source code page i can see the `css` file but it does not take any effect on website. The code bellow is what i used to call `css` and saw from view source code page and from my layout file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="/Content/css?v2">
```

Does anyone have any idea for this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used 
**External Style Sheet**

With an external style sheet, you can change the look of an entire website by changing just one file!

Each page must include a reference to the external style sheet file inside the `<link>` element. The `<link>` element goes inside the `<head>` section:

your code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="/Content/css?v2">
```

try like ths

`src` should change to  `href`

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/yourcssfilename.css">
</head>
```

Comment: @Son glad to help you